# Data retrieval from a string and consecutive writing into DB

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file from which I am reading data line by line, using the getline() function in C++. whenever i find the word "function" in the file, I need to extract a few strings/substrings from the same line and store them in a data structure. the difficulty that I have been facing and where I am stuck, is that I'm reading the lines using getline() in the form of string. but i cannot store the substrings because I am not sure about their ending position. I need to check character-by-character till i encounter a space/blank but cannot do that as it is in string format and not char....

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: C++11 have excellent support for [regular expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), or if you don't have that then [Boost have](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html). Or look into tools such as [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) and [yacc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

Comment: extracting a particular portion of the string,( A FUNCTION ABBBCCC ABCDDD),suppose FUNCTION and writing the next portion until delimited by space(AABBBCCC) and writing this information in a Database.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg lex and yacc are for compiler design, those tools are not really much usefull in this case.

Comment: @jnovacho While Lex and Yacc *mostly* is used for simple compiler/interpreter type of programs, they can be (and is) used to parse almost any kind of text input.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO.

The problem you are facing has been already solved many times. Probably the best answer you can get is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c). It contains in detail explanation how to split strings in C++. I hope it helps.

Comment: OK i ll be a more specific about the requirement.

Comment: OK i ll be a more specific about the requirement.
Assume a string,.. AA BB CC DD EE FF.

1)1st ly i wud have to linearly scan  multiple lines [most preferably with GETLINE()] in a text file,for a particular string,.lets say "BB".
2)Next,I wud have to write the data dat superceedes that string ,delimited by space,.which in dis case is "CC" , to a database(can be ne DB,not d major issue).
3)This process should iterate unless the end of the .TXT file is reached.
PS: The search string does not necessarily need to to be retrieved in the DB.I need assistance on how to procede.